# Convert mysql data from uppercase

Tags: mysql

How can I convert and update all my data in one colum from uppercase to uppercase just for the first letter of each word?

Need to update the database with the new values.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Looks like someone created a function for this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;


SELECT  CAP_FIRST(
    'this is totally like   @ TEST 1 right!'
)
```

Which returns: "This Is Totally Like @ Test 1 Right!"

Link: http://joezack.com/index.php/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/

Comment: Thanks. That helps. But is there a query which I can run against my database which can update all the values? That would be the ideal solution.

Comment: I would allocate a new table to test with, and try something like:

UPDATE TABLE SET column=CAP_FIRST(column)

Though I admit I haven't done this before.

Answer (score 0):

this may help...

http://joezack.com/index.php/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/

As per FAngel comment, I have completely plagiarized the content here in case the link dies:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;
So running the following code...

SELECT  CAP_FIRST(
    'this is totally like   @ TEST 1 right!' 
)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: No worries- i posted this more than 3 years ago before I was up to speed with SO

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/30-09-2010/mysql-how-upper-case-words

first define the function as shown, and then run an update statement:

`UPDATE table SET someColumn = UC_FIRST(someColumn);`